# How to create a shared model in Django?

Tags: django

I have a couple of models that have need of a common set of fields.  It is basically a set of various different types of contacts:

```
# models I would like to share
class Address(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(_('label'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    street1 = models.CharField(_('street1'), max_length=125, blank=True)
    street2 = models.CharField(_('street2'), max_length=125, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(_('state'), max_length=2, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(_('zip_code'), max_length=10, blank=True)

class Phone(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(_('label'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=50, blank=True)


# these are the models that I would like to have addresses and phone numbers
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, blank=False)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(_('email'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(_('website'), max_length=255, blank=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.CharField(_('photo'), max_length=255, blank=True)
```

I would like to share the `Phone` and `Address` models with the `Contact`, `Organization` and `UserProfile` models.  My first attempt was to add `ForeignKey` on each of `Contact`, `Organization` and `UserProfile` but after more research I believe this is backwards, so I moved the `ForeignKey` to `Address` and `Phone` but then discovered that `ForeignKey` can belong to one and only one model.  In addition to sharing this data structure between multiple different contact types, I would like the ability to add more than one address or phone number to a contact.  A contact could have a home address, work address, mobile number, and work number for example.  So I have basically 2 questions:

1) Is sharing a model in this way a reasonable thing to do?
2) How would I go about setting up the models?

Comment: Based on what you've said I believe you were right. As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) shows, a manufacturer (in your case a contact) can have multiple cars (in your case address and etc) and the FK should be in the car model.

Comment: The docs for one-to-one relationships has a great example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: create a parent class with common properties and inherit that class to child class and you may be able to add and override the parent class properties  as needed

Comment: It looks like you'd want to add a Many-to-many relationship with a through model to specify the type of relationship (work/home for addresses and mobile/fixed for phones). Look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

Comment: But the question is: will a `Contact` object and a `UserProfile` object share the exact same `Address` object? Since `Contact` and `UserProfile` are not related, you can't present a list of existing addresses to the person filling in the address. So it might make more sense to use ForeignKeys and not worry too much about really sharing, accept that there might be some duplicates here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add `ManyToManyField(Address|Phone)` (i.e. two M2M fields)
to `Contact`, `Organization` and `UserProfile`.

But that would mean different contacts/organizations/users could share addresses.
While this looks tempting, the problem with such a solution is that if someone 
edits an address of a contact, they also change the address for all the remaining objects in the system!

---

Another possible solution which avoids the above problem 
and doesn't require M2M fields or generic relationships would be to use
[multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

```
class Address(models.Model):
  entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
  ...

class Entity(models.Model):
  pass

class Contact(Entity):
  ...

class Organization(Entity):
  ...
```

(Under the hood Django creates implicit `OneToOneField`-s 
that point from `Contact` & `Organization` to `Entity`.)

Comment: I've been playing with the GenericRelations mentioned by @rydberg as well as the multi-table inheritance pattern you've mentioned here and I've found the multi-table inheritance pattern to be a little easier to reason about.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood correctly; you want your `Contact`, `Organization`, and `UserProfile` models to all have fields for `Address` and `Phone`. Moreover, they can each have more than one address/phone.

**Is this reasonable?** Sounds so to me.

**How could you go about setting up the models?** [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) spring to my mind.

Consider just `Contact` and `Address` for now. Your second attempt is correct: we have a [Many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relationship (one contact, many addresses), so we need to make `Contact` a ForeignKey field in the `Address` model, like so:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    <other_fields>
    contact = models.ForeignKey('Contact', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This allows you to assign multiple addresses to each contact.

Moving on, you essentially want your `Address` model to have multiple foreign keys: Contact, Organization, and UserProfile. One way of achieving this is to use Generic Relations. This makes use of Django's built-in "contenttypes" framework, and allows you to create `GenericForeignKey` fields that point to more than one model. I encourage you to read the docs linked, since generic relations aren't so trivial. In the end, you'll have something like:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    street_1 = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True)
    street_2 = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True)
    etc...

    models_with_address = models.Q(app_label='app_name', model='contact') | \
                          models.Q(app_label='app_name', model='organization') | \
                          models.Q(app_label='app_name', model='userprofile')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=models_with_address)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

With this, you can create several addresses for each of the models specified in the `models_with_address` query. To be able to query the addresses for a given contact/organization/etc., you'll need a [reverse generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations). Setting this up involves adding the line `address = GenericRelation(Address)` to the respective models.

For further generalisation, you could create a `ContactableModel` (or whatever) class:

```
class ContactableModel(models.Model):
    address = GenericRelation('Address')
    phone = GenericRelation('Phone')
```

Any model with an address and phone number (Contact, Organization, etc.) could then inherit this so that you don't have to repeatedly include those two fields. You could also improve the `models_with_address` limit, so that we have something like `limit_choices_to=<subclasses_of_ContactableModel>`.

Hope this helps!